# Regular Expression - Global Search Between 2 Whole Words

Tags: regex, match, words

I'm attempting to search for content between 2 whole words using a regular expression.  For example:

> all the girls went to the mall in
>   town.

In the above string I want to find the content between the word `all` and `to`:

```
(?<=all).*?(?=to)/g
```

However, it's finding two matches since the expression is not instructed to search between whole words only:

```
" the girls went " //between all and to
" in " //between m(all) and (to)wn
```

I had thought to add spaces in the expression, like this:

```
(?<= all ).*?(?= to )/g
```

but this will not work in the above string since `all` is the first word of the sentence.

How can I write the expression so that it finds all appropriate content between 2 whole words only, without partial word matches as shown in the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add word boundaries

```
(?<=\ball\b).*?(?=\bto\b)
```

\b is a no-width word boundary. It matches the beginning or end of a word (as defined by regex, of course)

Comment: "`\b` matches between a word character (0-9, A-Z, a-z, and the underscore) and any non-word character"

Comment: one more question:  suppose i want the returned content to include all except for white spaces, so instead of " the girls went " i would get "thegirlswent".  how do i match all (.*?) except for whitespaces?

Comment: @TheDarkIn: Just strip the spaces afterwards. Very easy: preg_replace("\s*", "", $result); You could do everything in one regex, but it would be a harder to read and understand. Don't try the "clever" stuff, go for readability.

Comment: ok, i'll keep it simple.  but to further my knowledge, suppose my word boundary included one space: (?<=\ball \b).  the following content is not found if it is prefixed with an additional space:  "all  the girls..." (all[SPACE][SPACE]the girls...).

Comment: you are right. The word boundary would not match between two spaces.